# Better way to get word count and character count

Tags: java

My task to count the number of words in a sentence and also characters count, the words in the sentence are separated by single or multiple spaces.

Here is the program I tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "  Hello        world";
    // Logic to get word count
    String[] words = input.split("\\s+");
    int count = 0;
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.length() > 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Word Count : " + count);

    // Logic to get character count.
    char[] array = input.toCharArray();

    Map<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (char key : array) {
        map.put(key, map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
    }
    System.out.println("Characters count:");
    map.forEach((k, v) -> {
        System.out.println(k + ": " + v);
    });
}
```

Output of this program:

```
Word Count : 2
Characters count:
 : 10
H: 1
e: 1
l: 3
o: 2
w: 1
r: 1
d: 1
```

The program is working fine, but in this program, I am using two arrays

```
String[] words = input.split("\\s+");

char[] array = input.toCharArray();
```

Is there a way to use a single array and improve the performance of this code?

Comment: Word count: `count = input.trim().split("\\s+").length;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to be honest, I doubt using only one array will have any improvement on performance, but if you really want to do everything with one single array, you could do the following.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String input = "  Hello        world";
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    int wordCount = 0;

    Map<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    char lastChar = ' ';
    for (char c: chars) {
        if (lastChar == ' ' && c != ' ') wordCount++;
        map.put(c, map.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
        lastChar = c;
    }

    System.out.println("Word Count : " + wordCount);
    map.forEach((k, v) -> {
        System.out.println(k + ": " + v);
    });

}
```

So, just iterate through the `char[]` and save the last char in a variable. Then, check if the last char was an empty space and the new one something different, then we could guess it is the start of a word. The rest is pretty much the same.

Comment: Ohh forgot to count those.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use an array for the word count.

All you have to do is count the number of times that the current character changes from whitespace to non-whitespace.

This will most likely not improve runtime performance, and there is a slim chance that you will save any noticeable amount of memory.